# Weak Self in GCD, accessing TableView property of self

Tags: swift, closures, grand-central-dispatch

I see a lot of code like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In this context, where `tableView` is a property of `self`, should one instead ensure `weak self` is captured like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I think so, but this type of "unsafe" code is so ubiquitous across codebases I wonder if I'm missing something?

Comment: why do you think second one is "unsafe"  ?

Comment: @zeytin - I’m guessing that Woodstock isn’t worried about the second one, but rather the _first._ He’s probably worried that it introduced a strong reference cycle (which it hasn’t). It doesn’t matter, though, as neither of these are unsafe. (The fact that he used the term “unsafe”, which has a very different and very specific meaning in memory management, was probably an accident, too.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said:

> In this context, where `tableView` is a property of `self`, should one instead ensure `weak self` is captured like this:
>
> ```
> DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
>     self?.tableView.reloadData()
> }
> ```

No, you don’t actually need to use `weak` reference to `self` in this case. There is no persistent strong reference cycle here. The worst that would happen (in the absence of `weak` reference) is that it will keep a strong reference to `self` until the dispatched block finishes running. But that closure will generally run practically immediately and the fleeting strong reference will be eliminated very quickly.

So, as such, no, you don’t have to use `weak` reference here. It is not technically incorrect to do so, but adds a syntactic noise for practically no benefit. Yes, we should be diligent about breaking potential strong reference cycles with `weak` references, but this is not one of those cases.

---

By the way, the choice of the term “unsafe” muddles the topic a bit. “Unsafe” has a very specific meaning when talking about memory references: It generally refers to dangling references to deallocated objects when not using runtime safety checks. As [The Swift Programming Language: Automatic Reference Counting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID57) says (emphasis from original):

> Swift also provides *unsafe* unowned references for cases where you need to disable runtime safety checks—for example, for performance reasons. As with all unsafe operations, you take on the responsibility for checking that code for safety.
>
> You indicate an unsafe unowned reference by writing `unowned(unsafe)`. If you try to access an unsafe unowned reference after the instance that it refers to is deallocated, your program will try to access the memory location where the instance used to be, which is an unsafe operation.

Obviously, both strong and weak references are safe (the former keeps the object from being released, the latter sets its references to `nil` when the object is deallocated). Even `unowned` references often employ runtime safety checks (though it still results in runtime error if you use a `unowned` reference after the object is deallocated). An “unsafe” reference is used in high-performance scenarios, where you are absolutely confident in your unowned references are being handled properly and that you’re willing to run your code without runtime safety checks.

I suspect you didn’t mean “unsafe” in this context, but I mention it so that you are aware of the very specific meaning that this word has within the context of ARC and memory management.

Comment: Thanks @Rob - as always. I understood a strong ref cycle is created if a closure captures self, and self captures the closure. I guess here `self` doesn't have a long lived (property style) reference to the GCD block, is that right?

Comment: The question is what the owner of the closure does with the closure after it calls it. In the case of GCD, they’re very good about releasing the closure after they’re done with it (thus breaking the strong reference “cycle”). But with something like a repeating timer or notification observer, the closure obviously can’t be released, so we must use `weak self` pattern. It varies.